# Groovy as List Question

Tags: groovy

I ran across this bit of code and to me it seems like its not needed is there any reason to do the following

```
def answers = [] as List
```

instead of

```
def answers = []
```

In groovy I thought that [] was the empty list so there would be no need to have the as List

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference, both create an `ArrayList` and `List` (`java.util.List`) is an interface anyway.